# How to search on PS Now app for PC?

Tags: pc, ps-now

I've just installed and opened PS Now from my PC and I don't know how to search for a game. There's only a list of categories, and scrolling down I can see some games ordered by A-Z.

I can't find a way to search by title. I've tried looking in the list of the starting letter I need, but there are only few games that are still repeating in cycle, and clearly several are missing.

I've added some on "my list" or something from PS app, hoping to access them easily, but I can't see that list anywhere.

So, here's my dumb question: How to search for a game?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it looks like there is no search functionality, which in my opinion is somewhat of a design flaw. See [this](https://www.makeuseof.com/how-to-access-and-use-ps-now-on-your-pc/#:%7E:text=Unfortunately%2C%20one%20major%20drawback%20of%20PlayStation%20Now%20on%20PC%20is%20the%20lack%20of%20a%20search%20function.) website which states:

> Unfortunately, one major drawback of PlayStation Now on PC is the lack of a search function ... You don't have options to search for games by genre or theme, as you do with the PS4 version of PlayStation Now. You can't even see all of the games on one screen, ordered from A-Z, which is an option with the PS4 version.

Comment: How could nobody notice this flaw? 2021 and no search function: anachronistic.